# Access to React component by ref before first render

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have component with some links. There is animated (`position: absolute`) line under the active link. So I need find out `offset().left` of active link before I set `left` to underline. But how? Before first render, there is no the element.

```
render() {
   var activeLink = 1; // For example, active link is the second link.
   var underlineStyle = {
       left: $hereINeedActiveLink.offset().left - $hereINeedContainer.offset().left;
   };

   return (
      <nav ref='container'>
         <a href='/' ref='link1'>Link 1</a>
         <a href='/' ref='link2'>Link 2</a>
         <a href='/' ref='link3'>Link 3</a>
         <div style={underlineStyle} />
      </nav>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should change your approach... Sometimes when something seems too complicated, thats because its meant to be done somewhere else. In this case you should let css handle styling the element. You just control what that style is in javascript by applying an active class to the element.

```
<a href='/' className={activeLink === 1 ? 'active':''}>Link 1</a>
<a href='/' className={activeLink === 2 ? 'active':''}>Link 2</a>
<a href='/' className={activeLink === 3 ? 'active':''}>Link 3</a>
```

[look at this fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/1et0hbb1/3/)

your css can go a few different routes to achieve a line at the bottom of the element. either you can do a border, or you can use a pseudo selector to create an element.

first you style each link

```
a {
    padding: 15px 10px;
}
```

border example

```
a.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

or pseudo example (with this example, you need to ensure that the anchor tags are `position: relative`)

```
a.active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[fiddle with a pseudo selector example](https://jsfiddle.net/1et0hbb1/4/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I cannot use `border-bottom` or `text-decoration`, because then it will not be possible animated move of underline between links after change active links.

Comment: @Vesmy ok then just use did mount for the initial position